# In 6502 assembler, trying to output integers after log statement

Tags: assembly, instruction-set, 6502

I'm using 6502 emulator site to output a series of integers and a log statement. I have coded the first set of integers and a log statement to output. But I'm not sure how to set another string integers to appear after the log statement. My output currently looks like this: 12345This Is Zero Plus One Then One Plus One Four TimesNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULL The NULLs are supposed to be 6,7,8,9,A.

This is the code I placed in the emulator.0xA9,0x00,0x8D,0x60,0x00,0xA9,0x01,0x8D,0x61,0x00,0xA9,0x06,0x8D,0x62,0x00,0xAD,0x61,0x00,0xA8,0xA2,0x01,0xFF,0x6D,0x61,0x00,0xAA,0xEC,0x62,0x00,0xD0,0xF3,0xA2,0x03,0xFF,0x25,0x00,0x00,0x54,0x68,0x69,0x73,0x20,0x49,0x73,0x20,0x5A,0x65,0x72,0x6F,0x20,0x50,0x6C,0x75,0x73,0x20,0x4F,0x6E,0x65,0x20,0x54,0x68,0x65,0x6E,0x20,0x4F,0x6E,0x65,0x20,0x50,0x6C,0x75,0x73,0x20,0x4F,0x6E,0x65,0x20,0x46,0x6F,0x75,0x72,0x20, 0x54,0x69,0x6D,0x65,0x73,0xA9, 0x06,0x8D,0x90,0x00,0xA9,0x01,0x8D,0x91,0x00,0xA9,0x0B,0x8D,0x92,0x00,0xAD,0x90,0x00,0xA8,0xA2,0x01,0xFF,0x6D,0x91,0x00,0xAA,0xEC,0x92,0x00,0xD0,0xF3,0x00

Do I need to put in some kind of break between the log statement and integers? I tried 0x00 to separate them but it didn't work.

I used this link to the emulator and this instruction set. https://tsiram.com/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUotF.jpg)

Comment: Normally people use an assembler, not dealing with only raw machine code (in hex or binary).  That image isn't a complete 6502 ISA listing, real 6502 has some other instructions.  It seems like you actually have a stripped-down variant of 6502.  (And an online simulator that apparently only accepts hex machine code, not assembly.  Many online CPU simulators have an assembler built-in, and the better ones have a debugger that lets you single step.)  **If you want other humans to look at your code, you should show a human-readable (asm source) version of it.**

Comment: Breakpoints and single-step debugging are an essential tool for assembly; I'd highly recommend looking for a 6502 simulator with that.  https://github.com/KyleRessLiere/6502-Virtual-CPU-CMP-422 might just be bare simulator; IDK if it has any extra functionality if run locally.

Comment: To add to @PeterCordes' completely valid comment: the supplied hex doesn't disassemble cleanly due to that simulator's invented opcode of `FF`. So there's no quick way to see what that code is meant to do.